# Can we use CostBasedJoinReorder in Spark SQL AQE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cost-based-optimizer

I'm wondering whether we can use join reorder cbo in AQE execution, so we can get fresh statistics from previous partial execution. Is there any pitfall?